# Need a Powershell script where it writes a log to a TXT file

Tags: powershell

This is my PowerShell script to Move files from One directory to other. But I am unable to track the files moved and also the Number of files moved,I need a log file for the same. So, Please help me with the script.

```
$Now=Get-Date

Get-ChildItem C:\DBM\Send\Backup_Old | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Now.AddDays(-1) } |
    Move-Item -Destination E:\DBM\Send\Backup\Backup_Old
```

Comment: You may use `robocopy`. It is made for this kind of tasks and it has logging built in. ;-)

Comment: Instead of ```| Move-Item```, try ```| foreach-object { count++; write-log $_; MoveItem … }``` where ```write-log``` is a function you write to do whatever logging you need…

Comment: ... or you could add the parameter `-PassThru` to `Move-Object` what creates an output object for each moved file. When you collect the output of the complete command line in a variable you can use the `.count` property to get the number of the moved files and you can pipe the variable to `Out-File` to have it in a log file.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Or instead of `Out-File` use [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript)